# How to prevent Finger-Touch (on touchscreens) with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, touch

Is it possible to prevent touch gestures on a TouchScreen monitors, tablets, phones using JavaScript?

Comment: Every gesture? or just prevent specific events?

Comment: every "touch" gesture conducted on a touchscreen!

Comment: even touch clicks? All clicks?

Comment: @MattDammon everything there is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by preventing the `touchstart` event. You're probably looking to do it on the body if you're doing it page-wide.

```
var body = document.body;
element.ontouchstart = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

You can also use `window.addEventListener` for a page-wide affect.

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

This will also allow others to hook into the `touchstart` event.

### jQuery

It's also possible to do with jQuery, via the `on` method.

```
$('body').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: "ontouchstart" is available in jQuery as $('a').on('touchstart'); or not?

Comment: (Feel free to accept my answer for this question. Stops people from running into this when looking for unanswered questions)

Comment: yes, I will.. please wait for 5 more minutes for the time delay.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a modified [jQuery Block UI](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/blockUI) to do this in the past.